# Parametrize cycloid in terms of its arc length

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can someone share how I can parametrize $\mathbf r(t)=\langle t-\sin t, 1-\cos t\rangle$ over the interval $0\le t\le 2\pi$ in terms of its arc length? That is, $\mathbf r(s)=\langle ?,?\rangle$ in terms of $s$, its arc length.

Thanks.

Comment: see ex. 9 of [this document](https://www.math.mun.ca/~jxiao/Assig3s.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**hint**

$$s(t)=\int_0^t\sqrt{x'^2(u)+y'^2(u)}du$$

$$=\int_0^t\sqrt{(1-\cos(u))^2+\sin^2(u)}du$$
$$=\int_0^t\sqrt{4\sin^2(\frac u2)}du$$

$$=2\int_0^t\sin(\frac u2)du=4(1-\cos(\frac t2))$$

then
$$t=2\arccos(1-\frac s4)$$